Warn about unsaved changes in code snippet
Context:

While writing a question or answer, an attempt to leave the page (by trying to close that browser tab or clicking on a link) triggers a confirmation dialog.

Moreover, returning to the same page will restore the draft even if you had confirmed to leave the page.


Problems:

If the only thing you did was draft a JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet (without writing other text and without clicking "Save & copy into post"), then there will be neither a confirmation dialog nor will that draft be saved. A lot of work on the snippet gets lost, and this is unexpected because it's different from how edits of the main text are handled and is against good practices.

If on the other hand you had reopened the "Code Snippet" dialog by clicking "edit the above snippet" and made some changes there, it is up for debate whether leaving the page should memorize the old version of the snippet as if you clicked "Cancel" or the new version as if you clicked "Save & copy into post". Either way, one of those versions gets lost, and some people might not expect that particular version to get lost.


